# Structural equation modeling

Tags: statistical-significance, multiple-regression

Could you please suggest to me any great guidelines as to how I could use the structural equation modeling for a survey. Any example using SPSS will be great.

Comment: This is a really broad question. SEM is a huge topic with entire books written about it. And "modelling for a survey" is very vague. What are you trying to find out? What data have you got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **You cannot use SPSS for Structural Equation Modelling (SEM). However, you have a number of feasible options:**

1) To use [R software](http://www.r-project.org/), which is free. Then, you can use the `Lavaan package`. It is a very convenient tool for SEM modeling. Please use [this Lavaan tutorial](https://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/tutorial.pdf) document for some real examples of how SEM can be implemented.

2) You can use [Mplus software](http://www.statmodel.com/). You have to buy it but it is a very powerful and convenient tool for SEM. Again, use [this user guide](http://www.statmodel.com/ugexcerpts.shtml) for examples of how SEM is used.

3) While SPSS itself cannot be used for SEM, there is SPSS-related software called [AMOS](http://www.ibm.com/uk-en/marketplace/structural-equation-modeling-sem). [This document](http://stat.utexas.edu/images/SSC/Site/AMOS_Tutorial.pdf) provides a number of examples of how AMOS is used for SEM. Usually, if your company or institution already has SPSS license, AMOS is also purchased as part of the SPSS bundle. However, that might not be the case, so you need to check. Anyway, currently IBM offers a 30-day free trial for AMOS. A principal advantage of AMOS is that it has a graphical user interface, which makes it easier to use for beginners. In contrast, R or MPlus can be a bit more challenging to start with if you never had any coding experience.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments.

Comment: @Elias you are most welcome. If you found this information helpful, please consider upvoting or accepting the answer by placing a green tick. Thank you in advance.